# Dynamically add keywords and their values to a python function from supplied strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a method, which can dynamically add keyword arguments to another function that I intend to call within this method, something like:

```py
def func(query1: str, query2: str):
    func2(query1, query2)
```

where, the `query1, query2` in the `func` are strings of the type `"a=3", "b=4"`, the func should essentially take these strings and then call them in a keyword argument way like:

```py
func2(a=3, b=4)
```

The a, b here are not fixed, they may vary, I mean to say I want to be able to take the `a` and `b` from the LHS of the string `"a=3"`

So my function takes the string `"a=3"` and parses the `"a"` as the keyword for the other function and the `3` as the value and calls the other function like `func2(a=3)`

I want to know if this kind of implementation is even possible or if there are any workarounds for achieving the same goal.

The reason why I want this is because I have a django application in which I want to create a model where I can store some filter rules and apply them each time that view is called, so I want to allow the user to select a bunch of filters and then I want to store them in the database and call those rules to get a queryset specific to that user's preferences.

```py
def some_view(request):
    # Get the filter rule strings from the model
    queryset = some_model.objects.filter(<Pass all the rules here from those strings>)
    return Response
```

edit: Add more details on the use case

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific with your minimal reproducable example ?

Comment: So you want to call `func2(a=3, b=4)` but only if `query1` and `query2` are defined? And leave out those arguments otherwise? Or not call `func2` at all? It's not quite clear what you want.

Comment: @TanishqVyas more specific as in? I do not know the way to do this, I just know I want that functionality

Comment: @RandomDavis I am actually planning to use *args for that, it should accept all such query strings and then pass them to the other function,

Comment: @AmartyaGaur what are the conditions for "dynamically adding" the keyword args? What do you want the function call to look like given different conditions?

Comment: @RandomDavis I have added the use case if that helps...

Comment: You can pass keyword arguments, `func(**kwargs) ` and unpack them there `filter(**kwargs)`. If they are empty, no filtering should be applied.

Comment: @Thymen those **kwargs have to be arguments themselves, can't I use strings, you see I need to save those set of rules, I do not know how else can I save them except when using char fields in a specific model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really understand what you want. You could translate those query strings to a `dict`, then use that to call the other function with `**kwargs`:

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a, b)

def g(*queries):
    return f(**dict((q.split("=", 1) for q in queries)))

>>> g("a=4", "b='string with = in the middle'")
4 'string with = in the middle'
```

Note: just `split("=")` might fail if the parameter is a string containing `=`; thus you might want to use `split("=", 1)` instead.

However, this passes all the arguments as raw strings; you might want to `eval`, or rather `ast.literal_eval` to the values, but that may also pose some risks. Something like this:

```
import ast
def g(*queries):
    return f(**{k: ast.literal_eval(v)
                for k, v in (q.split("=", 1) for q in queries)})
```

Comment: I would want to convert those LHS on the strings to keywords and the RHS to values for the f(a, b) as the a, b could be any acceptable value for django queryset filtering option

Comment: This would work as the filtering accepts string keywords, Thanks